# Invasive (adjective)

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

A native British teacher shared this;

Invasive: (especially of an action or sensation) tending to intrude on a person's thoughts or privacy
"Our neighbour is so invasive, he's constantly looking over the fence to see what we are doing in the garden"

However, when I checked several dictionaries including Oxford's, Cambridge's, and Britannica Dictionary, I couldn't find such a meaning. Does this meaning of 'invasive' really exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition you quote seems to be from the English Language Dictionary made available by Google, and provided by Oxford Languages, and obtained when doing a Google search on "Invasive definition". I can't find a way to create a separate link to it. However

- [Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invasive) gives:

> [sense 4] tending to infringe

- [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/invasive) gives:

> [sense 2] invading, or tending to invade; intrusive: *Every party we have is crashed by those invasive neighbors.*

- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/invasive) also giv "intrusive" as one meaning.
- [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/invasive) gives:

> [Sense 3] annoying because of being too close, too noisy, or too involved in people’s personal lives

In short, the meaning you were given is a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

Webster's New World Dictionary has as a second definition for invasive: "penetrating into the body". That is the sense used when we talk about invasive vs. non-invasive medical procedures.

Using "invasive" to describe a neighbor would be somewhat metaphorical, using the idea of penetration but only in regards to penetrating your thoughts or privacy.

I have heard counselors and psychiatrists speak about "invasive thoughts" -- distressing thoughts that are hard to ignore.

So while you may not have found a dictionary definition that matches what the teacher said, I believe "invasive" can certainly be used to describe the behavior of a nosy neighbor, especially one whose physical presence steps over boundaries, such as fences and personal space.

Comment: See the definitions linked in my answer.